# Group dates in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, date, foreach

I want to add a new line in order to group dates within a `foreach` loop.

Example:

```
2015-11-05
2015-11-05

2015-11-07

2015-11-10
2015-11-10
2015-11-10

... and so on
```

As I don't know how to accomplish this and as I don't find nothing after few days of Googling, I have only the standard code for a `foreach` to loop the data from a database.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datetime_published

foreach($rows AS $row) {
    echo $row['datetime_published'].'<br>';
}
```

The code above prints the dates like this:

```
2015-11-05
2015-11-05
2015-11-07
2015-11-10
2015-11-10
2015-11-10
... and so on
```

How can I accomplish this as the example shows?

**Database structure**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_visitor` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_place` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_post` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
`data_cover` varchar(50) COLLATE utf32_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
`data_subject` varchar(45) COLLATE utf32_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
`data_content` text COLLATE utf32_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
`datetime_published` datetime NOT NULL,
`datetime_edited` datetime NOT NULL,
`datetime_saved` datetime NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to save the previous value and compare it to the current one:

```
$prev = NULL;
foreach($rows AS $row) {
    $curr = $row['datetime_published'];
    echo "$curr<br>";
    if ($curr != $prev) {
        echo '<br>';
        $prev = $curr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$temp="":
foreach($rows AS $row) {
        $my_date = $row['datetime_published'];
        echo $my_date.'<br>';
         if(strcmp($my_date,$temp)==0)
           echo '<br>';
        $temp = $my_date;

    }
```

Comment: What should `$temp` contain? `NULL`? Your code (as it is right now) only prints as I showed under "The code above prints the dates like this".

Comment: Now no rows are added. Everything are on one and same row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95071/discussion-between-subin-c-poonamgode-and-erik-edgren).

Answer (score 2):

Both answers provided by Mureinik and Subin are good. But you also have the option to do the following

1. Edit your query to something like this

```
SELECT datetime_published,count(*) as count,`id_visitor`,`id_category`,`datetime_published`,`datetime_edited`,`data_content` FROM table group by `datetime_published` order by `datetime_published` desc
```

2. Now you have an array with the dates and the count it should print these dates. Then you can print it with a 'for loop'

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['count']; $i++) {
echo $row['datetime_published']." ".$row['data_content'] .'<br>';
}
echo "<br>";
```

**Complete Solution spoiler**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$con=mysqli_connect("dbhost","dbuser","dbpass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql = "SELECT datetime_published,count(*) as count FROM date group by `datetime_published` order by `datetime_published` desc";
//print $sql;
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    $var = "select * from date where datetime_published = '".$row['datetime_published'] ."'";
    print $row['datetime_published']."<br>";
        if ($results=mysqli_query($con,$var))
        {
            // Fetch one and one row
            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
            {
            print $rows['data_subject']. " " . $rows['data_content'];
            echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    echo "<br>";
    }


}
echo "<br>";

  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Many thanks! That worked besides for one thing. I have also the time and the subject for the blog posts within the `foreach` loop. As it is right now, the time and the subject are the same as the first date. How can I do so it also prints the correct time and subject for the post?

Comment: could you provide your db structure? and maybe some rows, then I could edit the answer

Comment: check out the new query, this should give you the option to print/echo the other fields also

Comment: That gave the same result as before :/ Please see my current code with your solution here: http://pastebin.com/CBzQUJP9 (only available for 1 day)

Comment: I will check more closely when I get home, but for now I can ask to put the date field  first and count second and then any other field you need and test then

Comment: Ok. Do so :) I tried to have `datetime_published` first, then `COUNT(*) AS count` and after that `data_subject`. Same result as before :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95084/discussion-between-davejal-and-erik-edgren).

Comment: Yepp. And I answered for 7 hours ago :)

Comment: Erik try the complete solution only changing your db properties

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the code you provided in your answer only prints `date<br>subject content<br><br>date<br>subject content<br><br>date<br>subject content[...]` where `date` is the date and time for the post and `<br>` is new rows on the website (the `<br>` are not visible on the website of course). I got Mureinik's answer to work so I will use that code instead :) Many thanks for trying! :)